# Svelte Native ListView - Horizontal

Tags: nativescript, svelte

I try out and build my first App on Svelte Native. I develop this for an Tablet.
The standard ListView only supports vertical stacking.
I need this for horizontal.

This part only works for vertical:

```
<listView items="{listOfItems}" on:itemTap="{onItemTap}">
    <Template let:item>
        <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
        <label text="{item}" />
    </Template>
</listView>

<script>
    import { Template } from 'svelte-native/components'
    let listOfItems = ['one', 'two', 'three']
</script>
```

I also try this:
Here i have the Problem that nothing is showing.

```
{#each one as ones}
    <button on:tap={addToList(ones)} text="{ones.name}" class="prod-btn" />
{/each}
```

So i need help to show a list of objects in an horizontal view.

Answer (score 0):

so it's not entirely possible to do that, yet. the same is for horizontally scrolling as svelte native is a new community project. what I would suggest is just using a stackLayout. here's an example with context:

we want a simple stackLayout:

```
<stackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="100%" height="150" background="blue">
   <label text="item 1" width="60" height="100%" marginRight="10" background="orange">
   <label text="item 2" width="60" height="100%" marginRight="10" background="green">
</stackLayout>
```

I hope it works for you, if it does not always try checking the svelte native API docs and try to work / experiment in the REPL (basically an online editor) to test stuff, so you don't accidentally break your app.

1. docs: https://svelte-native.technology/docs
2. REPL:
   https://svelte-native.technology/repl?version=3.58.0&example=hello-world